# Why would REGSVR32 not find a DLL that is clearly there?

Tags: dll

I'm installing a custom application on a brand new Windows 2003 Server.  A couple of DLLs need to be added and registered, and I have copied them to the server in the C:\WINDOWS\System32 folder -- which is where they have always been when we've had the application running on Windows NT and 2000.

However, when I try to register them using:

regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\nameoflibrary.dll

It gives back:

```
LoadLibrary("c:\windows\system32\nameoflibrary.dll") failed - 
The specified module could not be found.
```

The DLL is however right there.  I can see it.  If I copy the path to Windows Explorer and attempt to run it, it tells me that I can't run a DLL, so I know it's there.  One minor complication is that the DLLs were built in VB5 -- but the VB5 runtime is installed on the server, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a 64-bit Windows 2003 server?

Comment: No, it's 32-bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that a dependant module is missing.  You need to look at the getlasterror code to determine why the module was not found.

Comment: Yep. A module that was supposed to be installed by the main application didn't get installed.  Once this was corrected, the two DLLs registered correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Jim B. is probably correct.  Get [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and load {nameoflibrary.dll} -- it will show you which dependent DLL is missing.

Comment: Updated method is to use dumpbin.exe from Visual Studio bin directory: `dumpbin /dependents <file.exe/dll>`